# Cholesky and $P^T LDL^T P$ decompositions not corresponding

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am using the Eigen library to factorize a matrix $A$ both using the Cholesky and the $LDL^T$ factorization.

Basically, I correctly compute a matrix $C$ and check that $$A=CC^T,$$ then I correctly compute $P$, $L$, and $D$, and check that $$A=P^TLDL^TP,$$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix generated by Eigen. However if $D=\sqrt D(\sqrt D)^T$, $$C\neq P^TL\sqrt D.$$

This is really counterintuitive for me. Is there any reason about this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: In general, $C C^T = B B^T$ does not imply that $C=B$. For example, if $Q$ is a rotation, $C C^T = C Q Q^T C^T = (CQ) (CQ)^T$, and, in general, we do not have $C = CQ$.

Comment: @copper.hat, thanks a lot for your answer, I did not think to see this problem in this way. Then, I ask myself what is the meaning of the uniqueness of the Cholesky decomposition for positive definite matrices. Is it unique apart of a rotation of $L$?

Answer (score 1):

As copper.hat said in his comment, we generally cannot infer that $C=B$ if we only know that $CC^T=BB^T$.

However, to answer the question in OP's comment: this fact does not violate the uniqueness of the Cholesky factorization because to call $A=CC^T$ a "Cholesky factorization", we need that $C$ is lower-triangular; presumably the $P^TL\sqrt{D}$ that arose from the Eigen calculation was not lower-triangular.

(In particular, the uniqueness of Cholesky decomposition is a consequence of the uniqueness of [$LU$ factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).)